# What does /y in net time command mean?

Tags: windows

What does `/y` in the net time command mean?

I am synchronizing my clock with my forest root domain using the following command:

```
net time \\192.168.1.1 /set /y
```

Comment: Read the docs - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490948.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comment suggested a link to [Net services overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490948.aspx), but the information was not there (it leads to a page with broken links).

The [Net time](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490716.aspx)  page might have been one of the actual targets, but it does not mention `/y`.

However, [Synchronize Time via the Network](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-nt/nettime.html) does mention it, saying

> In the most basic format, `NET TIME` displays just the Date/Time of the system
>   clock of the specified computer. The option `"/SET"` stores this Date/Time info
>   to your local system-clock (*"Synchronizes the time"*), still prompting you to confirm
>   this adjustment. Defining the option `"/YES"` will synchronize the time without the prompt.

Comment: That first link (from the comments) *does* actually answer the question: "All net commands accept /y (yes) and /n (no) command-line options."

Comment: I didn't notice, since the broken links on the page were more interesting.

Comment: yes - I cannot traverse to any of the net-services-commands using the navigation pane on the left.